# Cassandra wih Hive

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive

Am new in cassandra and Hive. Now i want integrate cassandra with the Hadoop-Hive but how can i integrate the cassandra with Hive.

Answer (score 3):

You're in luck: DataStax just released Brisk, a Cassandra distribution integrating Hadoop and Hive.

http://www.datastax.com/products/brisk

Answer (score 2):

You can look in to WSO2 BAM2 to get an idea about Hive Cassandra integration.

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/bam2/

Answer (score 1):

You need a Cassandra java storage library.

And here is one https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-Cassandra

or one mine https://github.com/2013Commons/hive-cassandra