# Cassandra - Hive integration

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive

What's the best practice for integrating Cassandra and Hive?

An old question on Stackoverflow ([Cassandra wih Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935787/cassandra-wih-hive)) points to Brisk, which has now become a subscription-only Datastax Enterprise product.

A google search only points to two open jira issues,

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4131
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1434

but none of them has resulted in any code committed in one of the two projects.

Is the only way to integrate Cassandra and Hive patching the Cassandra/Hive source code? Which solution are you using in your stack?

Answer (score 1):

I did the same research a month ago, to reach to the same conclusion. 
Brisk is no longer available as a community download, and besides patching the Cassandra/Hive code, the only way to throw map/reduce jobs at your Cassandra database is to use DSE -- Datastax Enterprise, which I believe is free for any use but production clusters.

You might have a look at [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) which is based on [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/).

Answer (score 1):

There's an [open source Cassandra Storage Handler for Hive](https://github.com/riptano/hive) currently maintained by Datastax.

Comment: This repo is no longer available ... Any ideas? It has been moved to hive_old

Answer (score 0):

here is a git de cassandra hive driver with cassandra 2.0 and hadoop 2,
https://github.com/2013Commons/hive-cassandra

and others for cassandra 1.2

https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-Cassandra/tree/HIVE-0.11.0-HADOOP-2.0.0-CASSANDRA-1.2.9

Answer (score -1):

You can use an integration framework or integration suite for this problem. Take a look at my presentation "[Big Data beyond Hadoop - How to integrate ALL your data](http://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2013/04/26/slides-from-nosqlmatters-big-data-beyond-apache-hadoop-how-to-integrate-all-your-data-with-apache-camel-and-talend/)" for more information about how to use open source integration frameworks and integration suites with Hadoop.

For example, Apache Camel (integration framework) and Talend Open Studio for Big Data (integration suite) are two open source solutions which offer connectors to both Cassandra and Hadoop.